# web scraping with python with BeautifulSoup , find error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk001JpX8YqG_te4nMARfL4zgr0fsWQ%3A1590551416511&ei=eOPNXv7hHsnLrQH486_wBw&q=nzd+in+nis&oq=nzd+in+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIIxAnMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgIIADIECAAQQzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BQgAEJECOggIABCDARCRAjoHCAAQgwEQQzoHCAAQFBCHAjoFCAAQgwE6CQgjECcQRhCCAlDrHVinNWCqRWgAcAB4AIABgQKIAZMLkgEFMC40LjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')


soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'dDoNo vk_bk gsrt gzfeS'})
```

trying to **scrape** information from google, but getting the following error: "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"
but when trying to do soup.find not getting any results at all.
appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')`. Use `lxml` instead of `xml`.  You can try it:

```
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}

url = "https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk001JpX8YqG_te4nMARfL4zgr0fsWQ%3A1590551416511&ei=eOPNXv7hHsnLrQH486_wBw&q=nzd+in+nis&oq=nzd+in+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIIxAnMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgIIADIECAAQQzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BQgAEJECOggIABCDARCRAjoHCAAQgwEQQzoHCAAQFBCHAjoFCAAQgwE6CQgjECcQRhCCAlDrHVinNWCqRWgAcAB4AIABgQKIAZMLkgEFMC40LjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

allDiv = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'dDoNo vk_bk gsrt gzfeS'})

print(allDiv)
```